# Customized bash wildcard expansion

Tags: linux, bash

If I do

`*.c`

it will return a list of files ending with `.c`, separated by a space. However, I'd like it to instead return a list of files, prefixed with `#include "` and postfixed with `"\n`.

e.g. output

```
#include "blah.c"
#include "meh.c"
#include "hehe.c"
```

I want to pipe the results of this into `gcc -xc -` so bonus points if the command is a one-liner.

(And no, I don't want to just `cat *.c` because it'll lose source-location information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simpler way:

```
printf '#include "%s"\n' *.c
```

Comment: Very nice. Something like this is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like

```
for f in *.c ; do
  printf '#include "%s"\n' $f
done | gcc -xc -
```

should do what you want

However, `gcc`  accepts multiple source files, so you could just do

```
gcc -Wall *.c -o yourprog -lyourlibrary
```

You could also pass `-g -O -flto` to `gcc`

Comment: Great, that does the trick. Using gcc's multiple source file thing is a bit different, as it compiles all the files individually which means it wastes a huge amount of time processing the same headers over, and over again. (Plus i don't trust -flto too much)

Comment: If each of your `*.c` file is `#include`-ing the *same* common `header.h`, you could precompile that with `gcc  -c header.h -o header.h.gch`; and I don't think that parsing headers is a huge amount of time for C code (it may be so for C++ code). You could use the `-ftime-report` program argument to `gcc` to find out. And `-flto` works well with GCC 4.7!

Answer (score 1):

I didnt test this, but this might do it

for a in *.c ; do echo '#include "'$a'"' ; done | gcc -xc -

Comment: Great, thanks that does the trick. I however awarded the question to Basile as he beat you by a minute :D